# How to stop a Jenkins Pipeline build with using a closure processor

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How can I have a closure stop a build as aborted without looking like a failure?

In my original Jenkins file I have something like this:

```
node() {
 println 'should print'
 if (shouldStop()) {
   return
 }
 println 'should NOT print'
}

# Output
should print
```

The return out of the node block ends the build with whatever status is presently has and does not perform the additional actions.

If I have a closure in the mix things the unwanted code still executes

```
withMyAction(closure) {
 def result
 try {
   prepareEnv()
   result = closure()
 } finally {
  cleanUp()
 }
 return result
}

node() {
 println 'should print'
 withMyAction {
  if (shouldStop()) {
    return
  }
 }
 println 'should NOT print'
}

# Output
should print
should NOT print
```

It seems that my options are

- Stop via `throw new Exception` or `error()`
- Wrap my downstream sections of the job in `if status == ...`

Is there an approach where I can gracefully stop the build early without using `return` from Jenkinsfile as my approach?